# Flutter_bluetooth_serial connecting issue

Tags: android, flutter, raspberry-pi, bluetooth

I tried to connect Bluetooth from Android to Raspberry Pi using flutter_bluetooth_serial

However, the connection did not work and these problems occurred.

```
I/flutter (13317): Connect -> selected 3C:6D:89:63:DE:AA
I/flutter (13317): 3C:6D:89:63:DE:AA
D/FlutterBluePlugin(13317): Connecting to 3C:6D:89:63:DE:AA (id: 9)
D/BluetoothAdapter(13317): cancelDiscovery
D/BluetoothAdapter(13317): cancelDiscovery = true
D/BluetoothUtils(13317): isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null
W/BluetoothAdapter(13317): getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
I/flutter (13317): Cannot connect, exception occured
I/flutter (13317): PlatformException(connect_error, read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1, java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
I/flutter (13317):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:920)
I/flutter (13317):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:934)
I/flutter (13317):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:494)
I/flutter (13317):  at io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothserial.BluetoothConnection.connect(BluetoothConnection.java:57)
I/flutter (13317):  at io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothserial.BluetoothConnection.connect(BluetoothConnection.java:64)
I/flutter (13317):  at io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothserial.FlutterBluetoothSerialPlugin$FlutterBluetoothSerialMethodCallHandler.lambda$onMethodCall$4$io-github-edufolly-flutterbluetoothserial-FlutterBluetoothSerialPlugin$FlutterBluetoothSerialMethodCallHandler(FlutterBluetoothSerialPlugin.java:1007)
I/flutter (13317):  at io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothserial.FlutterBluetoothSerialPlugin$FlutterBluetoothSerialMethodCallHandler$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.r
```

I used the example code of flutter_bluetooth_serial and although there seemed to be no problem in the video, this problem occurred to me.

Also I added these permissions to AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

What's the problem here?

Answers I'll wait.
thank you

I want to try connecting to a Raspberry Pi on Android and transfer data if connected.